# How to make an image of a bootable dvd

Tags: dvd, iso-image, bootable-media

How can you create an image of a dvd that is bootable? And by that I mean create an image which will let you burn a new dvd which is also bootable.

What application should you use? And what actually makes the dvd bootable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc) and [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) have an option to create iso.
Or if you have [Nero](http://www.nero.com/) installed, you can copy the disc to NRG image and then convert it to ISO using the light application [Any To Iso](http://www.crystalidea.com/anytoiso). This method is easier if you have Nero installed already.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20040607211900/http://www.nu2.nu/bootcd/) explains what makes a CD/DVD bootable

Comment: I think you can just copy straight to iso, with nero.

Comment: Link to explanation is dead. Perhaps next time quote the relevant bit.

Answer (score 2):

The image will carry the ability to be boot-able.
All you need is to get the image out with some tool.
You could then burn the image to a blank DVD.
[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) will let you do these things.

This gets complicated if the source DVD is [DRM protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management).

Answer (score 1):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) should do it. I'm not sure what makes a DVD bootable though - presumably some kind of flag? It's something that's part of the data/image, not something physical on the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

[LC ISO Creator](http://www.lucersoft.com/freeware.php) is very small, lightweight, free and portable!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

1. Download, install, and run [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/)
2. Click on `Tools` and then `Make CD/DVD/BD Image File...` [image]
3. Check either `.iso` or the format you want to make the image [image]
4. Choose the destination folder [image: destination]
5. Name the file and click `Save`[image]

Comment: NOTE : for making an image bootable you have to use BOOT.IMA .this file will make an iso image bootable and can be done through POWER ISO.