# How to write/make bootable Dvd?

Tags: windows, installation, dvd, burning, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Bootable CD from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso)

How to make bootable Dvd?? I have copied files of my Windows DVD in my Pc and DVD is not working now I just write its DVD but its not bootable. I want to know that how to write a bootable DVD so that my Window can run from start... thanks

Comment: What form are the files for Windows on your hard drive? .ISO or just the setup files from another Windows DVD?

Comment: surely this has already been asked & answered.  i'm not finding a suitable duplicate tho.

Comment: It's not exactly the same @quack, but the answers nearly are

Comment: @quack quixote, I couldn't find one either if it makes you feel better, http://superuser.com/questions/20536/how-to-make-an-image-of-a-bootable-dvd is as close as it gets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple copy and paste only copies the files, not the boot information stored in the disc. You need to use the Copy DVD feature of a disc burning application to do this.

I recommend [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) or [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Use imgburn to make an ISO of your windows DVD then burn that ISO to your blank DVD with imgburn. Make sure the 'make bootable' option is checked. [Here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/7050.aspx) is some more detailed information.