# How can I create a DVD image on Windows Server?

Tags: dvd, iso-image, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I want to install a couple of VMs.

To do so, in Hyper-V, I can either provide access to the hosts DVD drive or provide an image of the installation media. Sadly, I don't have an image, just the disc.

So I would like to create an image from the disc for easier access later on. How can I do this preferably with Microsoft tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/20536/how-to-make-an-image-of-a-bootable-dvd?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a Microsoft tool. That doesn't mean there isn't one.
I do know free software that will do this for you.
http://www.imgburn.com/
See there screenshots link at the top of the page. There is a clear button to create an image file from disk. Which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: ImgBurn is actually what I'm using right now.

Comment: As sad as it is, as of about November 2015, ImgBurn 2.5.8.0 Setup file is now officially confirmed as a virus by Avira AntiVir. Link: https://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/23952-imgburn-2580-setup-file-is-now-officially-confirmed-as-a-virus-by-avira-antivir/